How to add more video effects in Cheese?
Previous versions of Ubuntu (more than ten years ago) seemed to have more effects than currently present in Cheese.
Is there any way to add more effects in cheese?

The solution is to install the following packages and restart cheese.
sudo apt install gnome-video-effects-extra gnome-video-effects-frei0r

